How to Integrate MS-Clarity in AMP Pages in 2024?
I have developed a website entirely using Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP).
I recently discovered Microsoft Clarity, but their installation instructions do not cover AMP, even for manual installation.
I tried integrating the JavaScript code provided for manual installation by simply pasting it into the  element as recommended by the manual instructions for regular HTML code.
It appears to work in the Clarity interface, but several severe errors are reported by AMP validation tools, including Google Search Console. As a result, my pages are not being served by the AMP cache provided by Google's proxy-based content delivery network (CDN).
Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a workaround to implement Clarity on AMP without errors?

What do you mean exactly by pasted the code into the header? Did you mean, that  you added the script tag with the clarity-code?

yes, as instructed in the recommandations for the manual installation, copied and pasted the Clarity tracking code in the element 

Did you tried to specify the type attribute? The AMP documentation that I found states that the script tag is prohibited. :-/ Maybe there is another way of adding custom scripts, that is ok for AMP? Maybe try the amp-script tag docs?

Tried to add the attribute type="text/javascript" to the 